# Windows 2012 r2 mirroring is not available

Tags: windows, raid1

I have two disks that are a little bit larger than 2TB. 
During Windows installation i selected the whole unpartitioned disk to install Windows to. After the setup realized that installer created one 2TB partition and left some unpartitioned space.

I wanted to create a RAID 1 but in Disk management this option is grayed out. "Convert to Dynamic disk" is gray as well. Is that because of the MBR limitations and i should use GPT somehow?

How should i install Windows then? Create GPT label and one big NTFS partition and then select it from the Windows installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use Diskpart during the installation process.

If you convert disk to GPT Windows installer will delete it and create MBR.
If you try convert to Dynamic you'll get error that it's impossible to do on a disk larger than 2TB (i had 3TB)
If before starting installation you create GPT and a partition setup will tell you that it can't setup itself on it.

So i see no options here. Installed without a mirror. It's interesting that after installation Windows Disk Manager absolutely normally handles GPT - creates partitions of any size, etc.

So i have no idea why doesn't the installer work ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn the system disk into a RAID from inside windows exactly. Disk manager with let you force individual partitions to be mirrored, including the system reserved and C, but its not a true mirror and the second drive wont be bootable in the event of a failure of the first. The best method is generally to enable raid in your system bios, build a basic hardware raid in preboot, and reinstall windows to that raid. (you'll most likely need motherboard drivers on a USB, but some very common raids will have native drivers.)

Comment: Can you show what documentation that makes this clear? I've seen similar comments on related threads but no specific references that say it isn't possible.